# Font Awesome's fa-spin spinning around wrong center

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm using this toggle menu template: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/navigation-sidebar-with-toggle .

I have replaced bootstraps glyphicon with font awesome's

```
fa fa-cog fa-spin
```

but the cog is spinning out of boundaries as if the center is not on the same line as the text. I can see that there is some issue with thesizing, but I cannot figure out where, any idea what am I doing wrong?

JSFiffle: https://jsfiddle.net/vidriduch/mpw2r8h2/1/

Comment: it mostly happend when you are using paddings with .fa. if you want it to spin, use margins instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a problem in the text indent

```
.sidebar-nav li {
    line-height: 40px;
    text-indent: 20px; //Remove this rule and use margin
}
```

And change this class rules

```
.sub_icon {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 65px; // remove it
    padding-top: 10px;// remove it
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I finally found how to fix it :

You have to align the icon.

```
<i style='text-align: center;' class='fa fa-cog fa-spin' ></i>
```

Comment: In something similar I added

```<i style="display:block; text-align: center;" class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i>
```

And that did the trick for me

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked to just add 2px padding to the top.

```html
<i className="far fa-lg fa-spin fa-cog" style="padding-top: 2px" />
```

Comment: This seemed to work for me, although I think the `2px` may depend on the font-size. At 14pt, I found that `padding-top: 1px` works well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using flexbox, had a similar problem.
Just add:

```
text-align: center;
display:flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Also, because your code is aligned to the left, you will have to add `margin-right: (pixels);` to align it according to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the image tag. The CSS padding-right caused all the issues for me.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it just needs

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Eg:

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-3">Label col</label>
    <input class="col-3 form-control" />
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin " style="display: flex; align-items: center;"></i>
</div>
```

note: I use bootstrap